# How to set up googleTest as a shared library on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, unit-testing, installation, googletest

Debian does not provide any precompiled packages for gTest anymore. They suggest you integrate the framework into your project's makefile. But I want to keep my makefile clean. How do I set up gTest like the former versions (<1.6.0), so that I can link against the library?

Comment: BTW, gtest builds are managed using autotools so the standard `./configure && make && make install` workflow should work just fine. I'm not sure if this warrants a post since it would be no different from compiling many other packages from source.

Comment: I guess not all users are as experienced as you. I recently came from Windows to Linux and I would have been happy to find something like this on StackOverflow.

Comment: Note that Google recommend that you DO NOT build a library, but instead include the GTest code into your project. See https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_it_not_recommended_to_install_a_pre-compiled_copy_of_Goog

Comment: Thats the first note in the answer.

Comment: If you want to build from source, you may check out [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51833099/8385554).

Comment: The link provided by @Mawg is broken (the wiki was removed), it seems to work but points to a page that isn't on topic anymore (quite confusing). The best that I can find as replacement are these build instructions: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md However that only explains how to build with cmake. For autotools, I found the following answer to work best: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36000856/1487069

Comment: Wow!! That ***is*** weird !!!  Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Before you start make sure your have read and understood
[this note from Google](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/36066cfecf79267bdf46ff82ca6c3b052f8f633c/googletest/docs/faq.md#why-is-it-not-recommended-to-install-a-pre-compiled-copy-of-google-test-for-example-into-usrlocal)! This tutorial makes using gtest easy, but may introduce [nasty bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183540/linking-error-when-building-google-test-on-mac-commandline/20974890#20974890).

### 1. Get the googletest framework

```bash
wget https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.8.0.tar.gz
```

Or get it by [hand](https://github.com/google/googletest/releases). I won't maintain this little How-to, so if you stumbled upon it and the links are outdated, feel free to edit it.

### 2. Unpack and build google test

```bash
tar xf release-1.8.0.tar.gz
cd googletest-release-1.8.0
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON .
make
```

### 3. "Install" the headers and libs on your system.

This step might differ from distro to distro, so make sure you copy the headers and libs in the correct directory. I accomplished this by checking where [Debians former gtest libs](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/amd64/libgtest-dev/filelist) were located. But I'm sure there are better ways to do this.

```bash
sudo cp -a googletest/include/gtest /usr/include
sudo cp -a googlemock/gtest/libgtest_main.so googlemock/gtest/libgtest.so /usr/lib/

# The easiest/best way:
make install  # Note: before v1.11 this can be dangerous and is not supported
```

### 4. Update the cache of the linker

... and check if the GNU Linker knows the libs

```bash
sudo ldconfig -v | grep gtest
```

If the output looks like this:

```
libgtest.so.0 -> libgtest.so.0.0.0
libgtest_main.so.0 -> libgtest_main.so.0.0.0
```

then everything is fine.

gTestframework is now ready to use. Just don't forget to link your project against the library by setting `-lgtest` as linker flag and optionally, if you did not write your own test `main()` routine, the explicit `-lgtest_main` flag.

From here on you might want to go to Google's [Googletest Primer](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/primer.md) documentation, and the [old docs](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/release-1.8.0/googletest/docs/Documentation.md) about the framework to learn how it works. Happy coding!

***Edit:***
This works for OS X too! See ["How to properly setup googleTest on OS X"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746232/how-to-properly-setup-googletest-on-os-x-mavericks/21045113#21045113)

Comment: Is there no `make install` target that you can use instead of manually copying the library and headers?

Comment: Cite of the output of the makefile: `'make install' is dangerous and not supported. Instead, see README for how to integrate Google Test into your build system.`

Comment: Have the files been renamed in the 1.8.0 version? There is no `include/gtest` as far as I can tell.

Comment: Your post is out-of-date. Please do not mislead people, `sudo cp -a libgtest_main.so libgtest.so /usr/lib/` does not work anymore. The file isn't even there to begin with.

Comment: I'd also like to know why debian removed a pre-installed shared library (they did so as per upstreams recommendations: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=802587). The wiki link given there does no longer exist though. So why was this the case?

Comment: your solution didn't work for me. The correct output of `ldconfig` didn't show up. `sudo make instal` worked for me.

Comment: Just run `make install` from 1.11 onward, this works on >=debian10

Comment: Why use `cp -a` instead of just `cp`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer and better to copy to `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` instead of to `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib`, respectively?

Comment: The ["note from Google"](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/36066cfecf79267bdf46ff82ca6c3b052f8f633c/googletest/docs/faq.md#why-is-it-not-recommended-to-install-a-pre-compiled-copy-of-google-test-for-example-into-usrlocal) you have at the top, which recommends not installing into `/usr/local`, no longer exists in the [latest FAQ](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/faq.md) from Google. In fact, `sudo make install` now installs into `/usr/local`, [as stated here](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/main/googletest). I think that warning can safely be removed.

Comment: Here is the quote: `sudo make install    # Install in /usr/local/ by default`

Answer (score 45):

Let me answer this specifically for ubuntu users.
First start by installing the gtest development package.

```
sudo apt-get install libgtest-dev
```

Note that this package only install source files. You have to compile the code yourself to create the necessary library files. These source files should be located at /usr/src/gtest. Browse to this folder and use cmake to compile the library:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake # install cmake
cd /usr/src/gtest
sudo mkdir build
cd build
sudo cmake ..
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Now to compile your programs that uses gtest, you have to link it with:

```
-lgtest -lgtest_main -lpthread
```

This worked perfectly for me on Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

Comment: Actually you don't have to copy libraries manually, there is a target for that in Makefile. You can just do it like that: 
sudo apt-get install cmake # install cmake
cd /usr/src/gtest
sudo cmake CMakeLists.txt
sudo make install 
That should be built and copy /usr/local/lib/

Comment: @AlexanderZinovyev I get "make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop." when I execute the "sudo make install"

Comment: "sudo make install" worked on Ubuntu 18.04, but didn't work on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @AhmedNassar: "sudo make install" does just the same thing as "sudo cp *.a /usr/lib". So, if install option is not available in generated Makefile, you just copy them manually

Comment: There is no need to manually `sudo cp *.a /usr/lib`, just repalce it with `sudo make install` should be fine.

Comment: I had to compile with `-lgtest -lgtest_main -lpthread` to make it work.

Answer (score 29):

It took me a while to figure out this because the normal "make install" has been removed and I don't use cmake. Here is my experience to share. At work, I don't have root access on Linux, so I installed the Google test framework under my home directory: `~/usr/gtest/`.

To install the package in ~/usr/gtest/ as shared libraries, together with sample build as well:

```
$ mkdir ~/temp
$ cd ~/temp
$ unzip gtest-1.7.0.zip 
$ cd gtest-1.7.0
$ mkdir mybuild
$ cd mybuild
$ cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -Dgtest_build_samples=ON -G"Unix Makefiles" ..
$ make
$ cp -r ../include/gtest ~/usr/gtest/include/
$ cp lib*.so ~/usr/gtest/lib
```

To validate the installation, use the following test.c as a simple test example:

```
    #include <gtest/gtest.h>
    TEST(MathTest, TwoPlusTwoEqualsFour) {
        EXPECT_EQ(2 + 2, 4);
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        ::testing::InitGoogleTest( &argc, argv );
        return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
    }
```

To compile:

```
    $ export GTEST_HOME=~/usr/gtest
    $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$GTEST_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    $ g++ -I $GTEST_HOME/include -L $GTEST_HOME/lib -lgtest -lgtest_main -lpthread test.cpp
```

Comment: With the last line I get error: /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cczG727X.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN7testing4TestC2Ev'. I fixed this placing test.cpp before the libraries. i.e: g++ test.cpp -I $GTEST_HOME/include -L $GTEST_HOME/lib -lgtest -lgtest_main -lpthread

Comment: If linking against gtest_main (`lgtest_main`), there is no need to define your own `main` in the test file.

Answer (score 11):

If you happen to be using CMake, you can use [`ExternalProject_Add`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#module:ExternalProject) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9695234/424459).

This avoids you having to keep gtest source code in your repository, or installing it anywhere.  It is downloaded and built in your build tree automatically.

Answer (score 3):

**Update for Debian/Ubuntu**

Google Mock (package: `google-mock`) and Google Test (package: `libgtest-dev`) have been merged. The new package is called `googletest`. Both old names are still available for backwards compatibility and now depend on the new package `googletest`.

So, to get your libraries from the package repository, you can do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install googletest -y
cd /usr/src/googletest
sudo mkdir build
cd build
sudo cmake ..
sudo make
sudo cp googlemock/*.a googlemock/gtest/*.a /usr/lib
```

After that, you can link against `-lgmock` (or against `-lgmock_main` if you do not use a custom main method) and `-lpthread`. This was sufficient for using Google Test in my cases at least.

If you want the most current version of Google Test, download it from github. After that, the steps are similar:

```
git clone https://github.com/google/googletest
cd googletest
sudo mkdir build
cd build
sudo cmake ..
sudo make
sudo cp lib/*.a /usr/lib
```

As you can see, the path where the libraries are created has changed. Keep in mind that the new path might be valid for the package repositories soon, too.

Instead of copying the libraries manually, you could use `sudo make install`. It "currently" works, but be aware that it did not always work in the past. Also, you don't have control over the target location when using this command and you might not want to pollute `/usr/lib`.

Answer (score 1):

I was similarly underwhelmed by this situation and ended up making my own Ubuntu source packages for this. These source packages allow you to easily produce a binary package. They are based on the latest gtest & gmock source as of this post.

[Google Test DEB Source Package](http://drake.redwyvern.com/files/gtest-1.7.0.tar.gz)

[Google Mock DEB Source Package](http://drake.redwyvern.com/files/gmock-1.7.0.tar.gz)

To build the binary package do this:

```
tar -xzvf gtest-1.7.0.tar.gz
cd gtest-1.7.0
dpkg-source -x gtest_1.7.0-1.dsc
cd gtest-1.7.0
dpkg-buildpackage
```

It may tell you that you need some pre-requisite packages in which case you just need to apt-get install them.
Apart from that, the built .deb binary packages should then be sitting in the parent directory.

For GMock, the process is the same.

As a side note, while not specific to my source packages, when linking gtest to your unit test, ensure that gtest is included first (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=156639)
This seems like a common gotcha.

Comment: Your package gives me errors when I try to compile.  Any reason why?? here is my log test.cpp:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `testing::Message::Message()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::AssertHelper(testing::TestPartResult::Type, char const*, int, char const*)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x97): undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::operator=(testing::Message const&) const'
... its so long that I can't post the entire thing.  I did this in a brand new Ubuntu 14.04 VM so nothing else was installed except the necessary dependencies.

Comment: @ddelnano Yeah i ran into this little google test gem too. Apparently the order of the shared libraries is important. When linking gtest to your unit test, try including gtest before other libraries.
When i hit this problem, this link solved it for me: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=156639

Comment: @ddelnano, also if your test suite does not have a 'main' defined then don't forget to link against 'gtest_main'.

Comment: I didn't include any other libraries. this is all i had in my file     `#include <gtest/gtest.h>
        TEST(MathTest, TwoPlusTwoEqualsFour) {
            EXPECT_EQ(2 + 2, 4);
        }

        int main(int argc, char **argv) {
            ::testing::InitGoogleTest( &argc, argv );
            return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
        }`

Comment: nevermind I didn't read the blog post until after I posted that comment.  It is now finally working!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody else gets in the same situation like me yesterday (2016-06-22) and also does not succeed with the already posted approaches - on `Lubuntu 14.04` it worked for me using the following chain of commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/google/googletest
cd googletest
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON .
make
cd googlemock
sudo cp ./libgmock_main.so ./gtest/libgtest.so gtest/libgtest_main.so ./libgmock.so /usr/lib/
sudo ldconfig
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer from askubuntu is what worked for me. Seems simpler than other options an less error-prone, since it uses package `libgtest-dev` to get the sources and builds from there: https://askubuntu.com/questions/145887/why-no-library-files-installed-for-google-test?answertab=votes#tab-top

Please refer to that answer, but just as a shortcut I provide the steps here as well:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libgtest-dev
sudo apt-get install -y cmake
cd /usr/src/gtest
sudo cmake .
sudo make
sudo mv libg* /usr/lib/
```

After that, I could build my project which depends on `gtest` with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

This will build and install both gtest and gmock 1.7.0:

```
mkdir /tmp/googleTestMock
tar -xvf googletest-release-1.7.0.tar.gz -C /tmp/googleTestMock
tar -xvf googlemock-release-1.7.0.tar.gz -C /tmp/googleTestMock
cd /tmp/googleTestMock
mv googletest-release-1.7.0 gtest
cd googlemock-release-1.7.0
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON .
make -j$(nproc)
sudo cp -a include/gmock /usr/include
sudo cp -a libgmock.so libgmock_main.so /usr/lib/
sudo cp -a ../gtest/include/gtest /usr/include
sudo cp -a gtest/libgtest.so gtest/libgtest_main.so /usr/lib/
sudo ldconfig
```

Answer (score 1):

The following method avoids manually messing with the `/usr/lib` directory while also requiring minimal change in your `CMakeLists.txt` file.  It also lets your package manager cleanly uninstall `libgtest-dev`.

The idea is that when you get the `libgtest-dev` package via

```
sudo apt install libgtest-dev
```

The source is stored in location `/usr/src/googletest`

You can simply point your `CMakeLists.txt` to that directory so that it can find the necessary dependencies

Simply replace `FindGTest` with `add_subdirectory(/usr/src/googletest gtest)`

At the end, it should look like this

```
add_subdirectory(/usr/src/googletest gtest)
target_link_libraries(your_executable gtest)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `buster` and `bullseye` one can install the following three packages without compiling anything:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtest-dev libgmock-dev googletest
```

This includes gmock.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the excellent answers [from @ManuelSchneid3r here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13513907/4561887) and [@amritkrs here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41954177/4561887), I have finally been able to put together (over more than 1 year of effort now) a more up-to-date set of instructions, as well as additional insight and information not provided by any other answer here, and which I have been trying to figure out for 5 years.

This includes a lot about gcc/g++ libraries, installing libraries, naming .a statically-linked library files, where g++ searches for includes, etc.

### How to install Google Test (`gtest`) and Google Mock (`gmock`) as shared, static `.a` libraries, system-wide, on Linux/Unix

*Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 with the latest (unreleased, `git pull`ed) version of [googletest](https://github.com/google/googletest) (more recent than v1.13.0).*

**If in a hurry, just run the several commands in the install section, then look at the "Example usage" shortly after.**

Note: googletest has undergone a variety of changes over the last few years. For example, gtest and gmock are now packaged under the same repo, here: https://github.com/google/googletest. So, following my instructions will install *both* for you.

##### 1. Install the latest gtest and gmock from source

If you want the latest *released* version, find it here: https://github.com/google/googletest/releases.

You can download it with `wget` like this, for instance:

```bash
# Download release v1.13.0
wget https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/refs/tags/v1.13.0.tar.gz
```

I prefer to just get the most-up-to-date content from the repo itself, however. Here are my full instructions, doing that:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cmake

# You can find some of these instructions, here: 
# https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/main/googletest
time git clone https://github.com/google/googletest.git
cd googletest        # "Main directory of the cloned repository."
mkdir build          # "Create a directory to hold the build output."
cd build
time cmake ..        # "Generate native make build scripts for GoogleTest."
                        # Takes ~2 seconds.
time make            # Run those makefiles just autogenerated by cmake above.
                        # Takes ~10 seconds.
sudo make install    # Install the .a library files, and headers, into 
                        # /user/local/.
```

Done!

You can now include the necessary headers into your files as shown above.

Note: here is the full output of what was copied over, or "installed", into `/usr/local` when you ran `sudo make install`:

```bash
googletest/build$ sudo make install
[ 25%] Built target gtest
[ 50%] Built target gmock
[ 75%] Built target gmock_main
[100%] Built target gtest_main
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gmock
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-more-matchers.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-function-mocker.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gmock/internal
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gmock/internal/gmock-pp.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gmock/internal/gmock-internal-utils.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gmock/internal/gmock-port.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gmock/internal/custom
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gmock/internal/custom/gmock-port.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gmock/internal/custom/gmock-matchers.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gmock/internal/custom/gmock-generated-actions.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gmock/internal/custom/README.md
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-cardinalities.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-more-actions.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-nice-strict.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libgmock.a
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libgmock_main.a
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/gmock.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/gmock_main.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/GTest/GTestTargets.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/GTest/GTestTargets-noconfig.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/GTest/GTestConfigVersion.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/GTest/GTestConfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-param-test.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-test-part.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-death-test-internal.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-filepath.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/custom
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/custom/gtest-printers.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/custom/gtest-port.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/custom/gtest.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/custom/README.md
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-string.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-type-util.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-param-util.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port-arch.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest_pred_impl.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-assertion-result.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-typed-test.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-spi.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest_prod.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-message.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-death-test.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-matchers.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libgtest.a
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libgtest_main.a
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/gtest.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/gtest_main.pc
```

##### 2. Background: the above installation instructions have just:

1. Installed gtest and gmock `*.a` static library files into `/usr/local/lib` so that you can build and run your gtest and gmock programs using these simple `g++` build flags (used by the linker, `ld`):

   1. `-lgtest`
      Link against the `/usr/local/lib/libgtest.a` static library file, which provides general googletest functionality.
   2. `-lgtest_main`
      Link against the `/usr/local/lib/libgtest_main.a` static library file, which provides a default `main()` function needed by googletest.
   3. `-lgmock`
      Link against the `/usr/local/lib/libgmock.a` static library file, which provides general googlemock functionality.
   4. `-lgmock_main`
      Link against the `/usr/local/lib/libgmock_main.a` static library file, which provides a default `main()` function needed by googlemock.
   5. `-pthread`
      Required by googletest, since it uses POSIX threads under the hood.

   *Notes:*

   1. Order matters. Ensure your flags above come *after* the files which need them.
   2. If you were to set the necessary CMake define to build shared dynamically-linked .so libraries instead of the static .a libraries we are building, then the `-l` flags above would cause the run-time linker to link against those instead, at run-time. See [@amritkrs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41954177/4561887) for more info. on that. Following my instructions, however, will cause those same `-l` flags to link at build-time instead, placing the entire pre-built .a static library file binaries into your executables.
2. Installed all gtest and gmock header files that you need to include in your programs into `/usr/local/include/gtest` and `/usr/local/include/gmock`, respectively.

   This allows you to includes the necessary files in your programs, like this:

   ```cpp
   // Include in your unit tests
   #include <gtest/gtest.h>
   #include <gmock/gmock.h>

   // Include in your production code to give gtest access to private members
   // in your classes, as friends, via the 
   // `FRIEND_TEST(TestSuiteName, TestName);` macro, for instance.
   #include <gtest/gtest_prod.h>
   ```

##### 3. Example usage:

```bash
# Build and run an example googletest unit test that comes in the repo:
# - required in this case: `-pthread`, `-lgtest`, and `-lgtest_main`

mkdir -p bin

time g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c++17 -pthread \
    googletest/googletest/samples/sample1_unittest.cc \
    googletest/googletest/samples/sample1.cc \
    -lgtest -lgtest_main -o bin/a && time bin/a
```

##### 4. Run an example unit test

Manually test-build and run a sample test included in the repo:

```bash
# (run while still in the googletest/build dir)
time g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c++17 -pthread \
    ../googletest/samples/sample1_unittest.cc \
    ../googletest/samples/sample1.cc \
    -lgtest -lgtest_main -o bin/a && time bin/a
```

Sample run and output:

```bash
googletest/build$ time g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c++17 -pthread \
>     ../googletest/samples/sample1_unittest.cc \
>     ../googletest/samples/sample1.cc \
>     -lgtest -lgtest_main -o bin/a && time bin/a

real    0m1.879s
user    0m1.740s
sys 0m0.135s
Running main() from /home/gabriel/GS/dev/temp/googletest/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 6 tests from 2 test suites.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 3 tests from FactorialTest
[ RUN      ] FactorialTest.Negative
[       OK ] FactorialTest.Negative (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] FactorialTest.Zero
[       OK ] FactorialTest.Zero (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] FactorialTest.Positive
[       OK ] FactorialTest.Positive (0 ms)
[----------] 3 tests from FactorialTest (0 ms total)

[----------] 3 tests from IsPrimeTest
[ RUN      ] IsPrimeTest.Negative
[       OK ] IsPrimeTest.Negative (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] IsPrimeTest.Trivial
[       OK ] IsPrimeTest.Trivial (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] IsPrimeTest.Positive
[       OK ] IsPrimeTest.Positive (0 ms)
[----------] 3 tests from IsPrimeTest (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 6 tests from 2 test suites ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 6 tests.

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.002s
```

##### 5. Uninstall

To remove/uninstall gtest and gmock, just manually remove all of the files that were copied over by `sudo make install`. Hare are the commands to do that:

```bash
# remove the main libraries
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libgtest.a \
        /usr/local/lib/libgtest_main.a \
        /usr/local/lib/libgmock.a \
        /usr/local/lib/libgmock_main.a

# remove the include dirs
sudo rm -r /usr/local/include/gtest \
           /usr/local/include/gmock

# extras

# remove the package config (whatever that is)
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/gtest.pc \
        /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/gtest_main.pc \
        /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/gmock.pc \
        /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/gmock_main.pc

# remove cmake GTest stuff
sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/cmake/GTest
```

### Going further: general information about libraries; debugging; gcc/g++ compiler flags; etc.

1. When compiling, `g++` searches your include directories for all header files your code includes. The default C++ system-wide include paths can be found by running `$(gcc -print-prog-name=cc1plus) -v` and then pressing Ctrl + C after a second to kill it (see here: [Where does gcc look for C and C++ header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/344525/4561887)). They include primarily:

   ```bash
   /usr/include        # system-added includes
   /usr/local/include  # user-added includes

   # as well as some more include paths to pull in compiler includes
   ```

   Include directories also include any that you have passed to `g++` via `-I` flags, such as `-I"path/to/some/personal/include_dir1" -I"path/to/include_dir2"`, etc.

   Storing gtest's includes in `/usr/local/include` directly means that you never have to pass custom `-I` flags to specify where they will be. The compiler just always has them available now!
2. Similar to the above "include" concept, library files, such as statically-linked .a files (or dynamically-linked .so files) can be linked to your executable by passing them as inputs to `g++`.

   Example: this command, from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72108315/4561887), manually specifies the `gtest` and `gmock` include directories, as well as the pre-built .a files, and builds the `googletest/googletest/samples/sample1_unittest.cc` example program:

   ```bash
   # Note: the specified .a files here must actually be locally stored in
   # a local "bin" path, as specified in this command
   time ( \
       time g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c++17 -pthread \
       -I"googletest/googletest/include" -I"googletest/googlemock/include" \
       googletest/googletest/samples/sample1_unittest.cc \
       googletest/googletest/samples/sample1.cc \
       bin/libgtest.a bin/libgtest_main.a \
       -o bin/a \
       && time bin/a \
   )
   ```

   Or, by copying the includes to `/usr/local/include` and the .a static library files to `/usr/local/lib`, you can simplify that command greatly and run this instead! The include directories no longer need to be specified at all, and instead of passing `path/to/libgtest.a` and `path/to/libgtest_main.a`, you simply pass `-lgtest` and `-lgtest_main`, respectively, instead:

   ```bash
   time g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c++17 -pthread \
       googletest/googletest/samples/sample1_unittest.cc \
       googletest/googletest/samples/sample1.cc \
       -lgtest -lgtest_main -o bin/a && time bin/a
   ```
3. Instead of running `sudo make install` to install the gtest and gmock headers and libraries into `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib`, respectively, you can **manually install the header files and libraries** by copying them like this if you want:

   ```bash
   # manually install the .a libraries, and header files

   # give access to g++ flags `-lgtest`, `-lgtest_main`, `-lgmock`, and
   # `-lgmock_main`, by copying over the .a static library files
   sudo cp -i -t /usr/local/lib \
       lib/libgtest.a lib/libgtest_main.a lib/libgmock.a lib/libgmock_main.a
   # give access to include header files `<gtest/gmock.h>` `<gtest/gtest.h>`, 
   # `<gtest/gtest_prod.h>`, etc.
   # 1. gtest header file includes
   sudo cp -a path/to/googletest/googletest/include/gtest /usr/local/include
   # 2. gmock header file includes
   sudo cp -a path/to/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock /usr/local/include
   ```

   I first learned that concept [in @ManuelSchneid3r's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13513907/4561887). I tested it myself.
4. Without header files installed or a `-I` path specified to them, you'll see failures to include your desired headers, such as `fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory` here:

   ```bash
   eRCaGuy_hello_world/cpp$ time g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c++17 -pthread  googletest/googletest/samples/sample1_unittest.cc     googletest/googletest/samples/sample1.cc     -lgtest -lgtest_main     -o bin/a      && time bin/a
   googletest/googletest/samples/sample1_unittest.cc:46:10: fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory
      46 | #include "gtest/gtest.h"
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.

   real    0m0.046s
   user    0m0.039s
   sys 0m0.007s
   ```
5. Without libraries (.a or .so files) installed, and if you try to use `-lgtest` for example instead of passing `path/to/libgtest.a` directly, you'll see failures to link via the `ld` linker, such as `cannot find -lgtest` here:

   ```bash
   eRCaGuy_hello_world/cpp$ time g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c++17 -pthread  googletest/googletest/samples/sample1_unittest.cc     googletest/googletest/samples/sample1.cc     -lgtest -lgtest_main     -o bin/a      && time bin/a
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtest
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtest_main
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

   real    0m1.895s
   user    0m1.776s
   sys 0m0.119s
   ```
6. If you copy your library files to a known `g++` system-wide library path, such as `/usr/local/lib` (recommended for user-installed .a and .so libraries) or `/usr/lib` (for system-installed .a and .so libraries), the .a files **must** be named `libwhatever.a`, for instance, in order to be used as `-lwhatever`.

   You cannot call them `lwhatever.a`, or `libwhatever`. They *must* be named `libwhatever.a`.

   So, **having file `/usr/local/lib/libgtest.a` enables the `-lgtest` library linker flag**, but `/usr/local/lib/lgtest.a` does not.

   If your name is wrong and then try to use the `-lgtest` flag, you'll see the `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtest` linker error as previously shown above, since this library is not properly named and "installed".

   Again, this means if you call it `/usr/local/lib/libwhatever.a`, then you must use `-lwhatever` as the linker flag to that library.

   Note that per `ld --help`, the `-l` (lowercase "L") flags are apparently passed to the `ld` linker, and presumably the `l` stands for `l`ibrary. See my question here: [Meaning of `-l` (lowercase "L") flags in gcc/g++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75710217/4561887). From `ld --help`:

   > ```
   > -l LIBNAME, --library LIBNAME  
   >                             Search for library LIBNAME
   > ```
7. Looking at library files inside `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/lib`, the linker naming convention for libraries, whether static .a or dynamic .so files, seems to **require** that the library file name *must* be prefixed with `lib`!
8. Gtest uses POSIX threads (pthreads) under the hood, so you must always pass the `-pthread` flag to `g++` too.
9. A [google search for `g++ "-lpthread" vs "-pthread"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=g%2B%2B+%22-lpthread%22+vs+%22-pthread%22&oq=g%2B%2B+%22-lpthread%22+vs+%22-pthread%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.191j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) reveals this answer: [Difference between `-pthread` and `-lpthread` while compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23251828/4561887), which says that the difference between `-lpthread` and `-pthread` is historical, so on today's gcc/g++ and clang compilers, **you should always just use `-pthread` to bring in POSIX threads.**

   The `-lpthread` library is now an empty binary apparently and doesn't do anything except satisfy ancient requirements where that library must still be included in some places. But, `-pthread` handles that all for you, so just use `-pthread` alone and be done!

*That about covers it. I now know more about g++, libraries, and gtest.*

### References:

1. [Answer by @ManuelSchneid3r](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13513907/4561887)
2. [Answer by @amritkrs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41954177/4561887)
3. https://github.com/google/googletest

   1. https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/main/googletest
4. My Q&A: [How do I build and use googletest (gtest) and googlemock (gmock) with gcc/g++ or clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72108314/4561887)
5. MY Q: [Meaning of `-l` (lowercase "L") flags in gcc/g++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75710217/4561887)

Answer (score 0):

This will install google test and mock library in Ubuntu/Debian based system:

```
sudo apt-get install google-mock
```

Tested in google cloud in debian based image.

Comment: Hmm, no, I think this only installs `googlemock`, but it does not install `googletest` (gtest). At least that's what happened to me.

Answer (score -1):

For 1.8.1 based on @ManuelSchneid3r 's answer 
I had to do:

```
wget github.com/google/googletar xf release-1.8.1.tar.gz 
tar xf release-1.8.1.tar.gz
cd googletest-release-1.8.1/
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON .
make
```

I then did `make install` which seemed to work for 1.8.1, but 
following @ManuelSchneid3r it would mean:

```
sudo cp -a googletest/include/gtest /usr/include
sudo cp -a googlemock/include/gmock /usr/include
sudo cp `find .|grep .so$` /usr/lib/
```

Comment: Its been a while that I wrote this answer, let me know what is the problem with it if you think it has no value / is invalid.