# google testing missing DSO

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm learning to google test. I downloaded gtest, ran commands `./configure` and `make` and ended with

```
$ sudo cp -a include/gtest /usr/include
$ sudo cp -a lib/.libs/* /usr/lib/
```

i got all this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513905/how-to-properly-setup-googletest-on-linux). I tried to run this code

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
TEST(MathTest, TwoPlusTwoEqualsFour) {
    EXPECT_EQ(2 + 2, 4);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest( &argc, argv );
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

like this

```
 $ export GTEST_HOME=~/usr/gtest
 $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$GTEST_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 $ g++ -I $GTEST_HOME/include -L $GTEST_HOME/lib -lgtest -lgtest_main -lpthread test.cpp
```

but i received an error

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccVTj3Rk.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN7testing8internal9EqFailureEPKcS2_RKSsS4_b'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libgtest.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Am i doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Comment: AFAIK, you should not implement a `main()` if you link against `gtest_main`

Comment: so I should delete `main()`? What do you purpose

Comment: I tested it without the `main()` and compiled it like you did. The important thing is to add the libs after the `test.cpp`.

Comment: Please also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27091412/how-to-compile-a-gtest-cpp-file#27091541

Comment: I fixed this changing the position of test.cpp on the commandline. Just place it before the libraries. i.e: g++ test.cpp -I $GTEST_HOME/include -L $GTEST_HOME/lib -lgtest -lgtest_main -lpthread

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some errors in your setup.

You copied your **include/gtest** into **/usr/include** (`sudo cp -a include/gtest /usr/include`), but when you try to compile you tell the compiler to look for the gtest headers in the **~/usr/gtest** directory, not in the directory you set up before (**/usr/include/gtest**). The same things happed with the **lib/.libs/*** files. You copy them in a place and at compile time you ask for them in another place.

Keeping the following configurations:

```
$ sudo cp -a include/gtest /usr/include
$ sudo cp -a lib/.libs/* /usr/lib/
```

change `#include <gtest/gtest.h>` into `#include "gtest/gtest.h"`
and try to compile like this:

```
g++ -g -Wall <your .cpp files> -I /usr/include/gtest/ -L /usr/lib/ -lgtest -lgtest_main -lpthread
```

And you should see the following output after running the ./a.out file (or whatever name you assign to the executable file)

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from MathTest
[ RUN      ] MathTest.TwoPlusTwoEqualsFour
[       OK ] MathTest.TwoPlusTwoEqualsFour (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from MathTest (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the *.cpp source file in the front of library linked options:

```
g++ -I /home/gtest/googletest/include/ -L /home/gtest/googletest/ gtest_demo.cpp -lgtest -lgtest_main -lpthread
```