# How to compile a gtest cpp file?

Tags: c++, linux, unit-testing

On Ubuntu Linux, I have been following the `gtest` instructions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513905/how-to-properly-setup-googletest-on-linux) to install `gtest` with manually copying the header files and libraries to `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib`, respectively.

I then tried to compile the following code (`test1.cpp`)

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
TEST(MathTest, TwoPlusTwoEqualsFour) {
    EXPECT_EQ(2 + 2, 4);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest( &argc, argv );
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

with the following command

```
g++ -lgtest -lgtest_main -lpthread test1.cpp
```

just to see yet another unhelpful error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccQlmghI.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN7testing8internal9EqFailureEPKcS2_RKSsS4_b'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libgtest.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I fix this? Or is there another unittest framework which can be used in a SIMPLE way, with a working example?

The same question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232237/google-testing-missing-dso), but without an answer.

Answer (score 9):

Order of arguments to `g++` matters a lot. Source files should come before object files and libraries (from high-level to low-level libraries), etc. Read the chapter on [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC).

So try:

```
g++ -Wall -g -pthread test1.cpp -lgtest_main  -lgtest -lpthread
```

Comment: Creates a bunch of new errors:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Maybe pthread is not installed or something?

Comment: What does `-pthread` in your example mean?

Comment: -pthread tells gcc to use pthread libs, no need to use -lpthread

Comment: So you can also write just `-gtest_main` instead of `-lgtest_main` then...?

Comment: No, -pthread is a built in switch for GCC not a new way to link libs in general

Comment: Please read the documentation about invoking GCC... I linked it in my answer.

Comment: Still, I get a bunch of errors. Your answer only changed the content of the errors so far...

Comment: Should I start a new question to try to get an answer to my new problem?

Comment: I believe you should take several hours to read documentation (about GCC, Gtest, autotools, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

For linking the `gtest` library to your gtest, it seems one must use the static gtest libraries (for unknown reasons; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116622/undefined-reference-to-pthread-key-create-linker-error)). So instead of using the command line like

```
g++ -Wall -g -pthread test1.cpp -lgtest_main  -lgtest -lpthread
```

one must use

```
g++ -Wall -g  -pthread test1.cpp    /usr/lib/libgtest.a
```

Here, the library is located in `/usr/lib`, but depending on how `gtest` was installed the file `libgtest.a` is located somethere else.

Comment: Did you run `ldconfig` after installation of gtest?

Comment: Use `-L` to specify additional search pathes for libraries, instead of referring particular `.a` files directly.

Comment: Great find! To expand upon your answer, `g++ -Wall -g -pthread test1.cpp -lgtest`  works for me.