# How to install Google Test on Ubuntu without root access?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, googletest

I am trying to install Google Test according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21314020/6560773) on Ubuntu without root access, as I need learn and use it at work.

Managed to get these done in my own user folder:

```
$ mkdir ~/temp
$ cd ~/temp
$ unzip gtest-1.7.0.zip 
$ cd gtest-1.7.0
$ mkdir mybuild
$ cd mybuild
$ cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -Dgtest_build_samples=ON -G"Unix Makefiles" ..
$ make
```

It seems I already have gtest in /usr/src/gtest altough I don't want to use this, because it was not me who installed it and I'm not sure about its version, nor in its availability. Can't even delete it without permission.

Still the instruction ends as:

```
$ cp -r ../include/gtest ~/usr/gtest/include/
$ cp lib*.so ~/usr/gtest/lib
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: maybe if you ask this on http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say you want to install googletest in `/home/me/googletest`.

Browse to the googletest GitHub repo `https://github.com/google/googletest`. (Do not use a possibly -out-of-date version you may have got elsewhere.)

Using the **Clone or Download** link, either clone or download-and-extract
the source as (let's say) `./googletest` under your current directory `CWD` (where `CWD` is not `/home/me/`).

Then in `CWD`:-

```
$ mkdir googletest_build
$ cd googletest_build
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/home/me/googletest ../googletest
$ make
$ make install
```

After this, you will find:-

```
/home/me/googletest/
                lib/
                    libgmock.a
                    libgmock_main.a
                    libgtest.a
                    libgtest_main.a
                include/
                        gmock/
                            # gmock header files
                        gtest/
                            # gtest header files
```

You can then use gtest/gmock headers in your source code like:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
```

and compile and link a gtest/gmock program like:

```
g++ -pthread -I/home/me/googletest/include -c -o my-unit-tester.o my-unit-tester.cpp
g++ -o my-unit-tester my-unit-tester.o -L/home/me/googletest/lib -lgtest -lgmock -pthread
```

using the `-I...` option to tell the compiler where gtest/gmock headers reside and
using the `-L...` option to tell the linker where gtest/gmock libraries reside.

Pass `-pthread` to both compiler and linker because the gtest/gmock libraries are
built multi-threading by default.

After installing you no longer need either `CWD/googletest` or `CWD/googletest_build`.

You may wish to pass additional options to `cmake`, in which case the build products will differ as per the meaning of those additional options.

Comment: Will certainly try tomorrow, thanks for the explanation kind sir.

Comment: After make install command this is what I get:
**_make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop._**
What does it mean? my home/me/googletest stayed empty.

Comment: Did you get and use the latest googletest master source from https://github.com/google/googletest as the answer says?

Comment: I did not use the master folder, just the newest release, 1.7.0. I think I misunderstood you there. However reading on since, I found this comment saying I should avoid make install command: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13513907/6560773 I'm a little confused now.

Comment: @MattSom gtest-1.7.0 is 3 + 1/2 years old and so is the other SO answer you have read. Both are out of date. I well remember that `make install` was not supported on gtest-1.7.0. It is supported now. Delete any gtest-1.7.0 materials and start from scratch, following the steps in my answer.

Comment: Just tried this morning. Works fine and dandy. I've been trying to get this done for days, and none of the other installation guides worked for me. Thank you very much, cant display vote yet but please accept my +1 here for the time!

Comment: I saw only static library, how can we have both static lib(.a) and shared lib(.so) at the same time?