# How to reconfigure Google Test for a 32-bit embedded software?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 32bit-64bit, googletest

I've managed to install Google Test according to [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395984/how-to-install-google-test-on-ubuntu-without-root-access)

My problem is the following: I have to test projects which are being developed for an embedded software with a 32-bit operating system, so I need to reconfigure Google Test from 64-bit.

With the old 1.7.0 version it is know that the solution was this:

```
autoreconf -fvi
./configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu "CFLAGS=-m32" "CXXFLAGS=-m32" "LDFLAGS=-m32"
make
```

This is how I tried now with the new version:

```
cd home/CWD/googletest/googlemock
autoreconf -fvi
./configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu "CFLAGS=-m32" "CXXFLAGS=-m32" "LDFLAGS=-m32"

cd home/CWD/googletest/googletest
autoreconf -fvi
./configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu "CFLAGS=-m32" "CXXFLAGS=-m32" "LDFLAGS=-m32"

cd ..
mkdir googletest_build
cd googletest_build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/home/me/googletest ../googletest
make
make install
```

Did this, because I could not find configure files anywhere else but results shown in the terminal were the same as with the 1.7.0 version's reconfiguration.

However after using:

```
make UTEST=yes project_Name
```

I get this:

```
Linking... project_Name
GTEST_LDFLAGS=-L ../../googletest//lib/ -lpthread -lgtest -lgtest_main -lgmock -lstdc++!
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../../googletest//lib//libgtest.a when searching for -lgtest
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libgtest.a when searching for -lgtest
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libgtest.a when searching for -lgtest
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtest
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../../googletest//lib//libgtest_main.a when searching for -lgtest_main
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libgtest_main.a when searching for -lgtest_main
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libgtest_main.a when searching for -lgtest_main
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtest_main
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../../googletest//lib//libgmock.a when searching for -lgmock
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmock
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The projects env variables are set to 32-bit in the makefile, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Looking at the error message I am thinking: Is it my gcc version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To build 32-bit googletest using [my answer that you have referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38409897/1362568)
just follow the same procedure but instead of running:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/home/me/googletest ../googletest
```

run:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-m32 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/home/me/googletest ../googletest
```

If you are making even a personal installation of 32-bit googletest on a 64-bit host
it would be a good idea to make it obvious that it is 32-bit, e.g. by using the like of:

```
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/home/me/googletest_32
```

Answer (score 2):

We build google test with our applications itself. We did not use any pre build library, we simply include the needed stuff in our build toolchain like this fragment in the Makefile shows:

```
include /opt/foreign_components/gmock-1.7.0/gmock.mk

OBJ_SERI_BASIC = \
        $(GMOCK_OBJ) \
        $(COMPONENT_HOME_SERI)/unittest/src/test_virtual.o \
        $(COMPONENT_HOME_SERI)/component/name_value_pair.o
```

and the gmock.mk contains:

```
GMOCK_PATH=$(HOME)/foreign_components/gmock-1.7.0

GMOCK_OBJ= \
       $(GMOCK_PATH)/fused-src/gmock_main.o \
       $(GMOCK_PATH)/fused-src/gmock-gtest-all.o

GMOCK_INCLUDE=\
          -I$(GMOCK_PATH)/fused-src/gmock/ \
          -I$(GMOCK_PATH)/fused-src
```

So any flags and changes to the build will also be affect the test framework. So we build it with different compilers, targets and also for 64 and 32 bit on various platforms.

Comment: Interesting to know for 1.7.0, so +1 from me. Still I've been told [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395984/how-to-install-google-test-on-ubuntu-without-root-access#comment64292387_38409897) that 1.7.0 is an old version, and should use the new distribution now. First I will try @Mike Kinghan's solution, but many thanks for this explanation as well! :)

Comment: @MattSom: I see no reason why this solution will not work with current "versions". A little remark: "+1"? can't see it :-)

Comment: I see none as well for now, because I'm really a rookie with Google Test. Mike has just advised it, and I want to follow that way and try it, until it seems I need another perspective. About upvote: It is saved there, but it says it won't be displayed, until I have 15 reputation points.

Comment: @MattSom: The method to directly use the source in the project is mentioned in the README.md of the project as first solution. That is simply adding two files to your build. No further need of any precompilation, library configuration and installing. Simply two files adding... Give it a try :-)

Comment: Okay. The project I need to test piece by piece is a little vast in code quantity, but does have makefiles naturally, so I will certainly try every solution, just for curiosity if nothing else.