# GoogleTest compilation error in Maven nar build - undefined reference to `testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo

Tags: c++, maven, googletest, maven-nar-plugin

I am trying to experiment with Google test with Maven. So, I installed it using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513905/how-to-setup-googletest-as-a-shared-library-on-linux). I then created `dummyTest.cpp` for testing and added it in pom.xml to execute the test. While I do `mvn clean install`, I am getting following error -

```
[INFO] 1 total files to be compiled.
[INFO] 1 total files to be compiled.
[INFO] Found 1 processors available
[INFO] Found 1 processors available
[INFO]
Starting Core 0 with 1 source files...
[INFO]
Starting Core 0 with 1 source files...
[INFO] Linking...
[INFO] Linking...
[INFO] Starting link {4.8.3 -L/usr/lib -Bdynamic -lgtest -L/usr/lib -Bdynamic -lgtest_main -Bdynamic -lpthread -fexceptions -lstdc++}
[INFO] Starting link {4.8.3 -L/usr/lib -Bdynamic -lgtest -L/usr/lib -Bdynamic -lgtest_main -Bdynamic -lpthread -fexceptions -lstdc++}
[ERROR] /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libpthread.so when searching for -lpthread
[ERROR] /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libpthread.so when searching for -lpthread
[ERROR] /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libm.so when searching for -lm
[ERROR] /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libm.so when searching for -lm
[ERROR] /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libc.so when searching for -lc
[ERROR] /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libc.so when searching for -lc
[ERROR] /home/sshakya/MavenC/Recent_Backup/COE/testlibrary/target/test-nar/obj/amd64-Linux-gpp/dummyTest.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
[ERROR] dummyTest.cpp:(.text+0x1f2): undefined reference to `testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, testing::internal::CodeLocation, void const*, void (*)(), void (*)(), testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*)'
[ERROR] collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

The `dummyTest.cpp`, `pom file` and the `project structure` I am using is as follows :-

```
//
//      File:   dummyTest.cpp
//
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
TEST(dummyTest, AlwaysTrueTest) {
  EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}

//
//      File:   pom.xml
//
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.coe</groupId>
<artifactId>testlibrary</artifactId>
<packaging>nar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
    <skipDeploy>false</skipDeploy> 
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>   

<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>          
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
            <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <layout>NarLayout20</layout>
                <libraries>
                   <library>
                        <type>executable</type>
                        <run>true</run>
                    </library>
                </libraries>
                <linker>
                    <name>g++</name>
                    <sysLibs>
                        <sysLib>
                            <name>pthread</name>
                        </sysLib>
                    </sysLibs>
                     <libs>
                          <lib>
                            <name>gtest</name>
                            <type>shared</type>
                            <directory>/usr/lib/</directory>
                          </lib>
                          <lib>
                            <name>gtest_main</name>
                            <type>shared</type>
                            <directory>/usr/lib/</directory>
                          </lib>
                    </libs>
                </linker>
                <tests>
                    <test>
                      <name>dummyTest</name>
                      <link>shared</link>
                    </test>
              </tests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[image]

It seems that I am doing it the right way reading from other blog posts and stackoverflow Q&A, but I could not figure out what is causing this problem. Any help or any hint towards the right direction would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check for contradicting versions of gtest in the search paths: Is the same gtest.h included during compilation as used for the library libgtest{,_main} you link to?