# What are the steps to build LLVM from source for Ubuntu Bionic Beaver?

Tags: llvm

Not all Kaleidoscope examples compile. Some do.

In the build process of LLVM Cmake complains "- Failed to find LLVM FileCheck"

My interest is in developing a toy compiler using LLVM - on a Ubuntu Bionic Beaver laptop, 64 bit. Therefore I needed to compile LLVM from source. The documentation says Cmake, gcc/g++, clang and zlib are required for the build. Yes, that is true. I found out the hard way this list is incomplete.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install -y cmake gcc g++ python build-essential opam ocaml
sudo apt install -y checkinstall python-pygments python-yaml llvm

opam init /* and say yes to creating a profile
opam config env
opam install ctypes ctypes-foreign 
opam depext conf-llvm.6.0.0     /* and said Y to install
opam depext conf-m4.1           /* and said Y to install
opam depext conf-pkg-config.1.1 /* and said Y to install

sudo apt install libxml2-dev libplist-dev
sudo apt install llvm-7-tools

/*the z3 package is outdated, need to build from source:
mkdir z3 /*somewhere
git clone https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3
python scripts/mk_make.py
cd build
make 
sudo checkinstall /* y and enter

cd <to sourceroot of llvm>
git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git
cd llvm-project
mkdir build; cd build
cmake -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../llvm
make -j2
```

Kaleidoscope examples from Chapters 3 and 8 compile fine. The output from the toy compiler resulting from Chapter 8 even does compile and link to a working program. The examples from the Chapters 2, 4, 5, 6, 7 and 9 don't compile.

Answer (score 3):

You also need googletest as a shared library with current source code (27-04-2019) for it to compile. It is not stated as a requirement which was very frustrating when I had errors building llvm, clang, lld and clang extra tools.

Best place for the current code is: [github.com/google/googletest](https://github.com/google/googletest)

The best answer for how to build googletest is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513905/how-to-set-up-googletest-as-a-shared-library-on-linux)