# How to properly setup googleTest on OS X aside from XCode

Tags: c++, macos, googletest

How do I setup gTest, so that I can link aganist the library? I will code in vim, so I just want to install the libraries, unlike the [XCode setup](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/XcodeGuide). Goal is to be able to link a project against the library by setting `-lgtest` as linker flag and optionally, if I did not write my own test mainroutine, the explicit `-lgtest_main` flag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before you start make sure your have read and understood 
[this note from Google](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/FAQ.md#why-is-it-not-recommended-to-install-a-pre-compiled-copy-of-google-test-for-example-into-usrlocal)! This tutorial makes using gtest easy, but may introduce [nasty bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183540/linking-error-when-building-google-test-on-mac-commandline/20974890#20974890).

#### 1. Get the googletest framework

```
$ wget https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.8.0.zip
```

Or get it by [hand](https://github.com/google/googletest). I guess I won't manitain this little How-to, so if you stumbled upon it and the links are outdated, feel free to edit it.

#### 2. Unzip and build google test

```
$ unzip gtest-1.8.0.zip
$ cd gtest-1.8.0
$ ./configure
$ make
```

#### 3. "Install" the headers and libs on your system.

```
$ sudo cp -a include/gtest /usr/include
$ sudo cp -a lib/.libs/* /usr/lib/
```

gTestframework is now ready to use. Just don't forget to link your project against the library by setting `-lgtest` as linker flag and optionally, if you did not write your own test mainroutine, the explicit `-lgtest_main` flag.

From here on you might want to go to Googles [documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/Documentation.md) about the framework to learn how it works. Happy coding!

Comment: if you code in vim, you'll find useful this plugin: [vim-gtest](https://github.com/alepez/vim-gtest)

Comment: on the latest OSX, at step 3, i get: "operation not permitted". i seem to be unable to create any folders at /user/include. what can i do?

Comment: put it in /usr/local/include

Comment: this tutorial is not working anymore .......

./configure
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Comment: Looks like they switched to cmake. Run `cmake .`

Answer (score 3):

It's adviced that you link statically. There's no secret. Being a bit offtopic, I use CMake in my projects, which I recommend, and here (https://github.com/oblitum/operations) I have setup a very basic skeleton project that links to gmock and gtest (it's also adviced by google that you use the same gtest from gmock, when you use gmock). In the `external` folder reside the external CMake files that actually import gtest and gmock through `ExternalProject_Add`. In the sample, I'm setting the `URL` as a file path in my system where gmock and gtest are downloaded, but, if you check CMake `ExternalProject_Add` docs you can see that download urls, online repository urls are also available, which can allow your build to download gtest and gmock, and cache it, automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I think **cmake** is an easy way to setup and use gtest on OSX. It works  without manually copying files. Unzip [gooletest-release-1.8.0](https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.8.0.zip), then

```
cd googletest-release-1.8.0

# create a build directory
mkdir build      
cd build

# build configuration
cmake .. -DBUILD_GTEST=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON

# build it 
make   

# installation
sudo make install
```

Afterwards, you can easily incorporate gtest in your project with the cmake commands

```
# sets GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS and GTEST_LIBRARIES
find_package( GTest REQUIRED )      

# adds the gtest include directory
include_directories( ${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

# links gtest
target_link_libraries( yourTestApp ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} )
```