# gtest with xcode. error: d: framework not found gtest

Tags: c++, xcode, googletest

I follow the [instruction](http://bitrage.de/wp/google-test-with-xcode-6-and-c11/) and the [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003624/cant-get-gtest-working-with-xcode-6-2) to setup gtest for xcode. But
it still doesn't work and i got the error below:

> Ld
>   /Users/xiaxin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Calculator-cchvzojufxzxgfdevhkifabakxpl/Build/Products/Debug/Tests
>   normal x86_64 cd /Users/xiaxin/Documents/xCode/Calculator export
>   MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.10
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
>   -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk
>   -L/Users/xiaxin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Calculator-cchvzojufxzxgfdevhkifabakxpl/Build/Products/Debug
>   -L/usr/local/lib -F/Users/xiaxin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Calculator-cchvzojufxzxgfdevhkifabakxpl/Build/Products/Debug
>   -filelist /Users/xiaxin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Calculator-cchvzojufxzxgfdevhkifabakxpl/Build/Intermediates/Calculator.build/Debug/Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Tests.LinkFileList
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -lgtest -stdlib=libc++ -framework gtest -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/xiaxin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Calculator-cchvzojufxzxgfdevhkifabakxpl/Build/Intermediates/Calculator.build/Debug/Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Tests_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/xiaxin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Calculator-cchvzojufxzxgfdevhkifabakxpl/Build/Products/Debug/Tests
>
> ld: framework not found gtest clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the GTest library to your library path. You can accomplish this on the commandline by setting `-L/path/to/gtest`