# Issue installing GoogleTest on OS X (Sierra)

Tags: c++, googletest

I am try to install GoogleTest for testing a C++ project on macOS 10.12.

I have retrieved the latest source, release-1.8.0 and am having issues building the library.  I have tried the following:

```
$ cd googletest-release-1.8.0 
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make
```

There are no errors, however the lib files don't appear to be created anywhere that I can find.

What am I doing wrong here? I don't know too much about CMake.

Comment: Yeah, it is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this on OS X; after the steps you listed, there's a subdirectory under `build/` called `googlemock/` containing `libgmock.a` and `gtest/libgtest.a`.

The headers are in the main folder under `googletest/include/gtest/`.

Alternatively, there's maybe some guidance in [this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746232/how-to-properly-setup-googletest-on-os-x-aside-from-xcode)

Comment: Perfect, thanks, I didn't think to look for the gtest files in the gmock directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **External Project** like this:

```
<<CMakeLists.txt>>

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(myproject)

# Enable ExternalProject CMake module
include(ExternalProject)


# Download and install GoogleTest
ExternalProject_Add(
    gtest
    URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.8.0.zip
    PREFIX include/gtest
    # Disable install step
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

# Create a libgtest target to be used as a dependency by test programs
add_library(libgtest IMPORTED STATIC GLOBAL)
add_dependencies(libgtest gtest)

# Set gtest properties
ExternalProject_Get_Property(gtest source_dir binary_dir)
set_target_properties(libgtest PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${binary_dir}/googlemock/gtest/libgtest.a"
    IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}"
#   "INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES" "${source_dir}/include"
)
# I couldn't make it work with INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
set(GTEST_LIB "${source_dir}/googletest/include")

# Create a libgmock target to be used as a dependency by test programs
add_library(libgmock IMPORTED STATIC GLOBAL)
add_dependencies(libgmock gmock)

include_directories(${GTEST_LIB} ${GMOCK_LIB})
add_executable(test_exec testmain.cpp someotherfile.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_exec libgtest libgmock)
```

Should work.